# How to extract specific substring from a string using a one liner

Tags: javascript, regex

Input: `parent/123/child/grand-child`

Expected output: `child`

**Attempt 1**:   `(?<=\/parent\/\d*)(.*)(?=\/.*)`

Error: *A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width*, look behind does not accept * but I don't know the width of the number hence must use it

**Attempt 2:** (works but 2 liners):

```
const currentRoute='/parent/123/child/grand-child'
let extract = currentRoute.replace(/\/parent\/\d*/g, '');
extract = extract.substring(1, extract.lastIndexOf('/'));
console.log('Result', extract)
```

How do I get the extract with a one liner, preferably using regex

Comment: Why don't you use a capturing group instead with match? `console.log("parent/123/child/grand-child".match(/parent\/\d+\/(\w+)\/.*/)[1]);`

Comment: I know you said preferably regex, but `.split("/")[2]` will work too

Comment: @Akshay totally missed that one, tnx
Thefourthbird how would i do that with a capture

Comment: Does the regex I answered not work for you?

Comment: @EugenSunic See the example in the comments.

Comment: @Andre it's fine however the solution from The fourth bird is nicer

Comment: @Thefourthbird is there anyway to avoid that subgrouping so that I don't need to access that array in the end?

Comment: You could use the quantifier in the lookbehind, but that is not widely supported. It is in Chrome and Nodejs for example.

Comment: You could update the pattern to `(?<=parent\/\d*\/)([^\/]+)(?=\/)` and see it in Chrome https://regex101.com/r/CA7LNH/1 Note that the `.*` in the lookahead at the end can be omitted.

Comment: Also a JavaScript only solution: `var child = currentRoute.substring(8, currentRoute.lastIndexOf('/')).split("/").pop();`

Comment: @Andre too dirty...

Comment: Alright well using match you're always going to have to use [1] instead of [0], but if you really want [0] you can use `currentRoute.replace(/\/parent\/\d*\//,'').split("/")[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current pattern will match *123/child* instead of *child* only as there is a forward slash missing after `\d*` (note the `*` means 0 or more times)

It will also over match (See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOrvMG/1)) due to the `.*` if there are more forward slashes present.

---

Instead, you could make use of a capturing group and use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```
parent\/\d+\/(\w+)\/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f8Oj2w/1)

The value is in capturing group 1.

```js
let res = "parent/123/child/grand-child".match(/parent\/\d+\/(\w+)\//);
if (res) console.log(res[1])
```

---

A pattern with a lookbehind to get the value `child` could be

```
(?<=parent\/\d*\/)([^\/]+)(?=\/)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U9uOSA/1)

**Note** that this is not yet widely supported.

```js
let res = "parent/123/child/grand-child".match(/(?<=parent\/\d*\/)([^\/]+)(?=\/)/);
if (res) console.log(res[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
currentRoute.match(/\/parent\/(?:.*)\/(.*)\//)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format is fixed, then use `.split("/")[2]` to get 3rd element

```
console.log(currentRoute.split("/")[2]);
```

> "child"

---

To match the *parent* part of the string use `.match(/^parent\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)/)[1]`

```
console.log(currentRoute.match(/^parent\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)/)[1]);
```

> "child"